# How Can I Pass Variable Via Hyperlink To Another Page using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass php variable to another page using html link
here is my code

```
                 <a href="home.php?name= <?php echo $user ?>"  ac=Darshboard" style="color:#F00">Home</a>
```

I want to pass variable $user through link `<a href="home.php?name= <?php echo $user ?>".` Please use the above code to help correct on my link with variable $user.

Comment: why pass using alink when you have ti in your session variable - $_SESSION['user_info']['name']

Comment: Is that space after `name=` intentional?

Comment: I dont know if you want to get info user though your get from "name" if you want, then dont do it, it is not secure at all. As previsouly said, you should use sessions, good luck

Comment: @ThomasP1988 the funny thing is, he's already got the name in his session

Comment: check for errors using http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php - Also look at your rendered HTML source. It will reveal what your PHP/SQL looks like.

Comment: How can i pass the `$_SESSION['user_info']['name']` through the url? pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
<a href="home.php?name= <?php echo $user ?>"  ac=Darshboard" style="color:#F00">Home</a>
```

with

```
<a href="home.php?name=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_info']['name']; ?>" ac=Darshboard" style="color:#F00">Home</a>
```

and your code will be fine.

Comment: Still not passing variable via url here is url it displays `http://localhost/gande/home.php?name=`

Comment: What is the **url** of this page? Paste that, also did you try to echo `$user`?

Comment: url to the page is `http://localhost/gande/login.php` I echo `$user` this way `"home.php?name=<?php echo $user ?>"`

Comment: `$_GET` basically gets the value of variable through your url. Change your url to `http://localhost/gande/login.php?user=Someone`. It will work. Maybe you might wannt try doing `<a href="home.php?name=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_info']['name']; ?>"  ac=Darshboard" style="color:#F00">Home</a>`

Comment: Your last comment worked well for me. That is the exact thing i wanted to get.

Comment: Vote up and tick if you find the answer helpful :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A generic example, `foo.php`, creating a link to `bar.php?name=baz`, when accessed as `foo.php?name=baz`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="bar.php?name=<? echo $_GET['name']; ?>">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok except:

```
<a href="home.php?name= <?php echo $user ?>"  ac=Darshboard" style="color:#F00">Home</a>
                       ^------------remove space from here
```

Comment: I have removed the space but it is not passing the variable via url `http://localhost/gande/home.php?name=`